# Dojo : asynchronous xhrGet returns - undefined?

Tags: dojo

I wrote a function to retrieve all the data for various arias like this..

```
 function retrieveData(dom_sclapi) { 
        var apiResponse; 
        dojo.xhrGet({ 
                url : dom_sclapi, 
                handleAs: handle, 
                //sync: true, 
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }, 
                preventCache: true, 
                //Success 
                load: function(Response) { 
                        apiResponse = Response; 
                }, 
                // Ooops!  Error! 
                error: function(Error, ioArgs) { 
                        //apiResponse = Error; 
                        //console.log(ioArgs.xhr.status); 
                } 
        }); 
        //apiResponse 
        return apiResponse; 
    }
```

But apiResponse returns an undefined on sync = false state (here when i comment the sync attrribute). Its returns correct data output on sync = true only. So this makes problem on chrome and IE in loading styles as the chrome and IE blocks all other actions on synchronous calls.

How can I overcome this situation ? What is the actual problem with my code?

Comment: instead of returning the response, return what dojo.xhrGet gives you back - thats the deferred mentioned below (.then, .addCallbacks(function succ, function err) etc), so if you hook up with a deferred you can also leave out 'load' and 'error' parameters

Comment: if you console.log(Response) inside your load I bet it is getting what you want. The problem as I see it is scope. You might want to hitch the scope of your load function to the calling context since it will execute on the window by default.

Answer (score 3):

You need to better grasp the idea behind sync and async code.

That is exactly the case it returns `undefined`, because it isn't synchronized and value isn't available yet. 
When you set as synchronized, the rest code execution will wait for function return, otherwise you let code continue without waiting for result.

When you're writing asynchronous code, you shouldn't expect it to return a value on the next line of code, as it will most likely wont. 
Instead you should create an event or a callback when return value becomes available.
The `load:` in this case is a callback, when request recieved response.

Also refer to documentation regarding [Deferred](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/Deferred.html) objects. They're also described in [xhrGet](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/xhrGet.html#dojo-xhrget)

Thus your code above may become something like this.

```
function retrieveData(dom_sclapi, callback) { 
        // Will return Deferred object
        return dojo.xhrGet({
                url : dom_sclapi, 
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }, 
                preventCache: true, 
                // Pass callback function to do something with response
                load: callback,
                error: function(Error, ioArgs) { 
                        //console.log(ioArgs.xhr.status); 
                } 
        }); 
    }
// Or get data by deferred object
retrieveData(url, null).then(function(Response){ /* Do something with response */ })
// Via callback
retrieveData(url, function(Response){ /* Do something with response */ });
```

Comment: fix the `handleAs`, no need to set it, if Response is an actual string of json, simply call `var object = dojo.eval(Response)` before processing it